# Task perform by crontab to redirect output to folder

Tags: python, bash, cron

I have a  script which I run every day at particular time so and I am using cron for this task and from within cron I am also trying to redirect the output which is ".txt" file to a folder.

0 14 * * * python /home/lab/Desktop/meet.py > /home/lab/Meet1 2>&1

without using "/home/lab/Meet1 2>&1 " path I am able to run script at a given time but I am not able to redirect my output to the folder provided with the path.

Is there any way to direct my txt file output to the given folder(Meet1) or my given command is wrong.

so I need help with crontab command to redirect my txt file output to given(Meet1 in this example) folder.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You should not redirect a stream into a folder but into a file. Given that `/home/lab/Meet1` really is an existing folder, try redirecting to e.g. `/home/lab/Meet1/output.txt` or so.

Answer (score -1):

Correct answer is already provided to redirect it to a file not directory, just to add:

```
# Below command will overwrite contents of temp file.

0 14 * * * python /home/lab/Desktop/meet.py> temp 2>&1

# Below command will append contents to temp file. 

0 14 * * * python /home/lab/Desktop/meet.py >> temp 2>&1
```